# What are the best resources to get started with Eclipse plugin development?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm interested in writing eclipse plugins where do I start?

What resources have helped you?

I'm looking for:
  1. Tutorials
  2. Sites devoted to plugin development
  3. Books

Comment: For people who come to this later - I put some skeleton plugins for people to play with at http://joereddington.com/4149/2014/09/24/eclipse-plugins/ there is some chat about what's fun to play with and links to the github...

Answer (score 4):

I have done quite a bit with an RCP application that made use of multiple plug-ins. This book helped me tremendously in all fronts: RCP framework and plug-in development:
[http://www.amazon.com/Eclipse-Rich-Client-Platform-Applications/dp/0321334612](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321334612)

The book walks you through the development of a IM chat client using RCP and plug-in development.

Also the eclipse site and IBM have some pretty good tutorials, here is one: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-ecplug/

Answer (score 3):

You can find a good step by step detailed tutorial here:

http://www.eclipsepluginsite.com/

Other tutorials:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-eclipse-snippet/index.html?ca=dgr-lnxw16RichEclipse

http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipsePlugIn/article.html

A decent book, that I've used is "[Eclipse: Building Commercial-Quality Plug-Ins](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321228472)".

Answer (score 1):

The RCP book mentioned above is great
Also there are some older online articles on the eclipse site starting with http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-RCP-1/tutorial1.html. Unfortunately they are a bit out of date.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse's own Help contains a Platform Plug-in Developer Guide. It is a suggested reading in IBM's site.

I'm trying to build a plugin myself. After reading a little bit of "Eclipse Plug-ins" book I missed a more tutorial style writing. Vogella tutorial is quite good. After doing it, I started reading some Eclipse code (as described by Vogella in his tutorial). And now I found the Eclipse's Help resource.

Answer (score 0):

Here's all the books available for developing Eclipse Plugins:
http://www.eclipseplugincentral.com/books-index-req-view_subcat-sid-4.html

Answer (score 0):

As Eclipse RCP is also based on plug-ins this might also help: [Eclipse RCP Introduction](http://www.vogella.de/articles/RichClientPlatform/article.html)